# Working tree change cannot be reset, checked out or forgotten in git

Tags: git, reset

The problem:

```
john@Johns-MacBook-Pro:~/projects/api (shop)$ git st
On branch shop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/shop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/Tests/Http/apiHttpTestBase.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
john@Johns-MacBook-Pro:~/projects/api (shop)$
```

I don't care about any changes on that file, I switched to this branch with a clean working tree. I didn't actually change that file (and I made sure my IDE is closed).

```
git reset --hard HEAD

john@Johns-MacBook-Pro:~/projects/api (shop)$ git st
..snip..    
        modified:   src/Tests/Http/apiHttpTestBase.php
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
john@Johns-MacBook-Pro:~/projects/api (shop)$
```

I get the same issue after running git stash etc. There appears to be no escape. A diff shows that every time I run the reset the contents change, yet git still thinks I've made a change!

What's infuriating is that the only thing I can do to get around this seems to be to destroy and re-clone the repo.. I'm sure reset --hard HEAD should work, yet I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Because this is a Mac and HFS is by default case-insensitive, there are two possibilities: line endings, or two files differing only in case (e.g., `src/.../apiHttpTestBase.php` vs `src/.../APIHTTPTESTBASE.PHP`). If it is the former, some care with LF vs CRLF will fix it. If it is the latter, the only really easy way to deal with it is on another (not-case-folding) system such as Linux, or anything not-Windows-and-not-Mac.

Comment: Hmm, looks like my mounted image that I thought was case sensitive was not. If it's still happening then I'll update this Q.

Comment: Yup, it was the filesystem. No idea why or what but switching to a normal FS worked.

Comment: The curious thing was that the filenames were identical. So very weird.